# What's the Python's file logic when reading vs writing or appending?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Probably a dumb question here, but it's my curiosity.

I firstly thought that when using "a", the method .append() is automatically incorporated in it which makes sense since adding "a" should already indicate to the program our final goal, but i don't really understand why it's not the case when using "r" and, instead, we have to add also .read() at the end of the line.

Here is an example:

```
file1 = open("test.txt", "a")    #no .append() or something needed here
file1.write("Hello")
file1.close()

var_lecture = open("test.txt", "r").read()    #.read() necessary
print(var_lecture)
```

Can someone give me a better understanding of this?

Comment: You are using `.write`

Comment: Why would you want or need `write()` to have a different name when opened for append? The way `O_APPEND` is documented in the underlying UNIX filesystem API, it makes all _writes_ automatically go to the end. The operations are still called writes; `O_APPEND` just provides an extra guarantee about their behavior, so you can have multiple programs writing to the same log file without overwriting each others' content (because, with that flag, they no longer each have their own independent position in the file that they're writing to).

Comment: See `man 2 open` to understand the API that Python is putting a frontend on top of.

Comment: BTW, you might see [Are language specs and their developments on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306471/are-language-specs-and-their-developments-on-topic/306474#306474) for an overview of why "why" questions on language design are generally not well-received here. Stack Overflow works best for questions with narrow, practical answers that can be proved to solve a problem. Arguing about how something _should_ be designed quickly devolves into dueling opinions, and we don't permit opinion-based questions.

Comment: The file API is the same regardless of which mode you use. The thing is that some of the API doesn't work if the mode isn't correct. Open in "r" mode and `.write` is there... but it raises an error if you use it. This is modeled from a function based API in C where functions like "read" and "write" are used. Those functions are available in the C library but its up to you to only use them at the right time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy There is no guarantee the the user is using a UNIX-like system

Comment: @JonKiparsky, sure, but C and POSIX semantics are the original inspiration for the API no matter what OS Python is being used on.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I guess I'm suggesting that system calls are maybe not the most edifying way to explain python's behavior to a beginner. At least it seems to me that a person asking this question is not a person who's familiar with the underlying UNIX calls, and just needed reminding of them.

Comment: @JonKiparsky, when I take on a student, which I do every however many years, I always teach from the bottom up. People who understand high-level interfaces without any understanding of what's going on underneath them are forever bound to the law of leaky abstractions: the things they're taught will not be true uncomfortably often, and they'll have no basis on which to understand what's _really_ going on. If someone is going to actually master their craft, bottom-up is the way to go.

Comment: (one can always argue about where "the bottom" is; with my last student, I taught a Scheme-based curriculum while assigning MHRD and TIS-100 as homework to get CPU design and assembly conceptually introduced, and made an effort to tie the two together -- explaining how the TIS-100 stack and Scheme's recursion capabilities tied together, f/e).

Comment: @Naky, please don't vandalize your own question. Replacing the title with gobbledegook makes it harder for people to find and learn from the answer, and can make the answer no longer make sense since it's written to address the question as previously asked. Clarifications and edits are great when they enhance the question, but care should be taken to make sure that correct answers still make sense in light of those edits.

Answer (score 2):

The option is changing the the way the method 'write' is writing into the file. If you use the option 'w' it will overwrite the whole file. If you are using 'a' it will append the text to the text, that is already in the file

```
def read_test():
    content = open("test.txt", "r").read()
    print(content)

def write_test():
    file = open("test.txt", "w")
    file.write("test")
    file.close()

def append_test():
    file = open("test.txt", "a")
    file.write("test")
    file.close()

write_test()
read_test()
# output: test
write_test()
read_test()
# output: test
append_test()
read_test()
# output: testtest
```

Comment: `w` doesn't _always_ overwrite the whole file, that's just when `O_TRUNC` is used (by not also including the `+` flag). Whether `O_TRUNC` is used and whether `O_APPEND` is used are orthogonal decisions; it's possible to open a file with _both_ of those flags at once! (In Python, that's easiest done with `os.open()`, allowing the individual flags to be passed explicitly).

Comment: Nice answer, succinct explanation with good examples. One suggested improvement: if you print the output directly as part of the example, rather than including a comment saying what you would expect to be the case, it would be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

when you use mode append this mean the pointer editor  After the last letter on the page
for example

```
text.txt  contain "my name is name"
f=open("text.txt",mode="a",encoding="utf-8")
f.write("  ggg  ")
f.close()
#result "my name is name  ggg  "
```

when you read you read letters from pointer position to last letter for example text.txt  contain "my name is name"

```
  f=open("text.txt",mode="a+",encoding="utf-8")
    print(f.read()) 
    f.seek(5) # to set it in poition 5
    print(f.read())
    f.close()  
#""      # so when you read it  is empty
#me is name
```

at the write mode you will create a new file and write from position 0 if  the file not exist , if exist the truncate function will be use that mean all letters after pointer(at position 0) will be deleted

if you want to append at specific positions
for example text.txt contain "my name is name"

```
f=open("text.txt",mode="r+",encoding="utf-8")
f.seek(7)
f.write("ggg")
f.close()
#result : my nameggg name
```

but this will make overwrite on file

```
f=open("text.txt",mode="r+",encoding="utf-8")

f.seek(7) # set poistion at 7
R = f.read() # "  is name"
f.truncate() # delate all letters after pointer 
#========================
f.seek(0) 
print(f.read()) #result: my name
#========================
f.seek(7) 
# we should reset pointer
f.write("ggg"+R)
print(f.read())
f.close()
# text.text contain: my nameggg is name
```